# In Android Maps Customized marker is not shown in real device

Tags: android, maps

In Android Maps When I show customized marker on maps its working fine in emulator? but the problem is not showing in My Motorola Device (android lolipop).How can we slove this problem please anyone know help me

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what actually happend for adding marker. Please try this:

```
 if (googleMap != null) { 
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)));

    }
```